# Загружать картинки из xml и создать адаптер

Tags: java, android, xml

Нужно парсить `xml` и создав адаптер, присвоить к `Listview` этот адаптер.
Сам парсинг `xml` нетрудно. В `xml` файле есть ссылки на картинки.

Каким образом правильнее будет скачивать эти картинки и создать адаптер.
не затянутся ли если сделать в Asynctask'е и когда все загружались создать адаптер?

И можно ли построчно добавить в адаптер когда загружалась картинка?

Comment: Используйте либу `Glide` - загрузка, кэширование и отображение одной строкой.

Answer (score 1):

1. В качестве загрузчика картинок, как написал @ЮрийСПб, используйте [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
2. В модели, которую хотите отображать в списке, храните ссылку на картинку отдельным атрибутом: (`String imageUrl`), например.
3. Не используйте `ListView` для реализации списка. Используйте `RecyclerView`, т.к. `ListView` устарел.
4. В методе `onBindViewHolder` (в адаптере для `RecyclerView`) загружайте картинку каждого элемента списка с помощью `Glide`:

`Glide.with(context)
.load(model.getImageUrl)
.into(holder.imageView;`

Подробнее о том, как реализовать список с RecyclerView, можно почитать вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru).

Comment: а не сложно ли RecyclerView для новичка?

Comment: Нет. Да и изучение ListView не даст никакого профита, т.к. его уже не использвют. Т.е., это будет пустой тратой времени